# How to pass array of values into one multi selection list view using patchValue

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, angular-material

I am facing one issue to pass array of values into a multi selection list (angular material) using patchvalue method in reactive form .

input array

```
list2=["BLUEBERRY","GRAPES","APPLE"];// the value that need to be selected in the list
```

The elements present in the list(by looping through the array list1)

```
list1 = ["PINEAPPLE","PAPAYA","BLUEBERRY","GRAPES","APPLE"];
```

Multi selection list

```
<mat-form-field>  
<mat-select class="add_input" formControlName="menu"  placeholder="Available Menus" multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let menus of list1" [value]="menus">{{menus}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

patchvalue function is

```
this.form.patchValue(
    {
      location:this.gps,
      menu:  <-- how to pass the list2 element here(direct reference is not working)

    }
  )
```

FYI - The reactive form is already initialized using FormBuilder

Comment: Just tried your code and it works perfectly well. Please provide a [mcve] that actually shows the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.form.patchValue({
  location:this.gps,
  menu: [...this.list2]
})
```